# / folder permissions

Tags: permissions, sudo, directory, gksu

I've changed / folder owner from root to administrator account.
Now no sudo commands are working.

It used to show sudoers are in mode 04666 it should b in the mode 04000
Then i did something and it is showing **`"sudo:must be setuid root"`**
help me out

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to change your permissions back to what they were. Many system programs have specific permissions requirements, and changing permissions outside of your home directory isn't a good idea unless you specifically know that it's safe to do.

If you changed a bunch of permissions and don't know their original values, you're looking at a reinstall. Fixing a large number of permissions would be really difficult to do correctly.

If you aren't able to use the `chmod` and `chown` commands due to your messed up permissions, boot into the live CD, mount your hard drive, and fix the permissions from there.

Comment: I cant run any commands begins with sudo :(
Do i have to reinstall ubuntu??
isn't there any other alternative ??

Comment: No. Just use the LiveCD to access your filesystem and change the permissions.